# How we show the selected ListView item in alert dialog box in a Sequence?

Tags: java

Here is my code, I don't know what will do to write to show the individual selected items.
how we can show the user id, name, and other details in selected listview view item to alert the dialog. box. The main problem is the position of the selected item.

- List item

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;



ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        // URL to get contacts JSON
        String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String gender = c.getString("gender");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String office = phone.getString("office");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("\n"+"id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put(""+  "email", email);
                    contact.put(""+"mobile", mobile);
                    contact.put("address",address);
                    contact.put("\n"+"gender",gender);
                    contact.put("\n"+  "home",home);
                    contact.put("\n"+"office",office);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });


            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }



        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                "mobile", "address", "gender"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile, R.id.address});


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id)
            {

               
                AlertDialog.Builder alert =  new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,contactList,

                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                        "mobile", "address", "gender"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile, R.id.address});

                contactList.get(position);
                alert.setAdapter(adapter, null);

           
                alert.setView(mView);
                final androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        textView.setText(text.getText().toString());

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();

            
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}